# Reskit v0.2 Mapping for json format

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

```
{
"JobID" : "aaaabbbb-dddd-eeee-ffff-aaaabbbbcccc",
"UserID": "11112222-dddd-eeee-ffff-111122223333",

"FolderVersions" :  [
                {
                    "FolderID" : "11112222-dddd-eeee-ffff-111122223333",
                    "Version" : "1.0"
                },
                {
                    "FolderID" : "11113333-dddd-eeee-ffff-111122223333",
                    "Version" : "1.2"
                },
                {
                    "FolderID" : "33332222-dddd-eeee-ffff-111122223333",
                    "Version" : "1.1"
                }
            ]
}
```

i have Job Class with jobid, userid and nsmutable_array "folderversion"

FolderVersions: is mapped using FolderVersion class having folder_id and version

i want FolderVersions mapped to folderversion array in job class

```
RKObjectMapping *jobMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Job class]];
[jobMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"JobID" : @"jobId",@"USerID":@"userID"
      }];



    RKObjectMapping *folderMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[FolderVersion class]];
    [folderMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"FolderID":@"folderID",

 @"Version":@"version",

 }];



    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescripor1 = [RKResponseDescriptor jobMapping
         method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:@"/xxx/response.php/json/response" 

keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a relationship mapping to your `jobMapping`, which links to the key in the `Job` class to the key in the JSON (`FolderVersions`) and specifies that it should use the `folderMapping` for the content:

```
[jobMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"FolderVersions" toKeyPath:@"folderversion" withMapping:folderMapping]];
```